# Excel 2010 - Why do Workbooks With Macros Ask to Save Changes

Tags: excel-2010, savechanges

Often when, working with workbooks that contain VBA macros, I can save the workbook and then immediately attempt to close it. Excel then asks if I want to save changes. What causes this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing - do you handle Workbook Open event? I.e. do you have a `Workbook_Open()` routine coded?

Comment: Yes, we do. How does that effect it?

Comment: Usually in the Workbook_Open(), there is some initialisation (date set-up, construction of collection or object) - that affects binary and marks a file as touched (changed). I am afraid I do not know details - I only noticed that behaviour before.

Answer (score 0):

The other possibility is that there are volatile functions on the worksheet(s) like NOW(), TODAY(), or DATE(), which may get recalculated every time the workbook is opened. If the value changes, then you'll get the prompt, as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There are no volatile function in the Workbook.